# Reference Request on consumer theory

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, consumer-theory

I am looking for a recent literature review of consumer demand theory and its empirical applications. I have tried common places (google scholar, jel and jep papers) but no success. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Not really what you are looking for, but this question is somewhat related: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/current-knowledge-about-the-empirics-of-consumer-theory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very nice survey by Aviv Nevo on [Empirical Models of Consumer Behavior](http://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/~ane686/research/ARE2011.pdf). He surveys some of the models used in the literature. In particular, he discusses two commonly used demand systems: multi-stage budgeting approaches and discrete choice models.

We may also find interesting [Recent Developments in Empirical IO: Dynamic Demand and Dynamic Games](http://aguirregabiria.net/wpapers/worldcongress_aguirregabiria_nevo_final_090112.pdf) by Victor Aguirregabiria and Aviv Nevo.